# Defining 4 dimensional numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I intend to define a four dimensional matrix and set all its values equal to `1`. Here is my code:

```
import numpy
t=(3,4,5,6)
a=numpy.zeros(t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3])

for x in range(t[0]):
    for y in range(t[1]):
        for z in range(t[2]):
            for w in range(t[3]):
                a[x][y][z][w]=1

print(a)
```

Could you please help me to debug it?

**Edit:** Here is what compiler says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: zeros() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

But if I do the same program with 3 arguments, it still has problems:

```
import numpy
t=(3,4,5)
a=numpy.zeros(t[0],t[1],t[2])

for x in range(t[0]):
    for y in range(t[1]):
        for z in range(t[2]):
                a[x][y][z]=1

print(a)
```

Comment: What's the problem with above code?

Comment: I do not know. I only use lame online compilers.

Comment: Did you see the output of print when you use lame online compiler?

Comment: Your call to `numpy.zeros` is wrong: try `a = numpy.zeros(t)` Also in any case, this is not an efficient way to set all elements of the array to 1. Just use `a[:] = 1` (or here, create the array  with `numpy.ones` instead of `numpy.zeros`).

Comment: And even if you decide to have the loops, it is also a bad way to index in multiple dimensions: use `a[x, y, z, w]` instead of `a[x][y][z][w]`

Comment: Check the function docs before randomly trying fixes or begging for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for shape in `numpy.zeros()` should be a single number or a tuple.

Corrected code,

```
t=(3,4,5,6)
a=numpy.zeros(t)
```

otherwise, the second argument will be considered as a data type and will give an error.

You can refer to the below link for better understanding, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: True, but why not take the opportunity to simplify `(t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3])` to `t`?

Comment: Hey thanks @alani, correcting the answer LOL. Why I didn't see that..